# How to use a variable to indicate a file descriptor in bash?

Tags: bash, io, exec, file-descriptor

I want to use a bash variable to indicate a file descriptor, like this:

```
id=6
file=a
exec $id<>$file
```

But the usage is wrong:

```
-bash: exec: 6: not found
```

So, how to use a variable to indicate a file descriptor in exec command?

Comment: did you try `${id}` AND/OR `eval ....` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: The next character is not a word character, so curly brackets won't help. `eval` looks like the only option.

Comment: It might help to update your question with the version of bash are you using. Good luck.

Comment: This works without quoting, but quoting still advisable:  echo foo >&${id}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use `eval` and put the entire expression in quotes.

```
eval "exec $id<>$file"
```

And do that every time you want to use `$id`.

Comment: You don't need to `eval` all usages, just the `exec` call to open the descriptor. There's examples of using a variable to reference a file descriptor in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41603787/113632).

Comment: @dimo414, interesting! Apparently since Bash 4.1, you can do [exec {varname}<&-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620630/6232717) and the like! I had no clue they (somewhat) fixed that annoyance

Comment: fyi:

`$id<$file # INPUT mode`
`$id>$file # OUTPUT mode`
`$id>>$file # APPEND mode`
`$id<>$file # INPUT and OUTPUT mode`

Answer (score 36):

The accepted answer is correct, but [as of bash 4.1](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges), you can use automatic file descriptor allocation, and in that case you  don't need `eval`:

```
file=a
exec {id}<>"$file"
```

Then you  can use  it like this:

```
echo  test >&${id}
```

or:

```
fsck -v -f -C ${id} /dev/something
```

Comment: It seems that "id" must be fixed in the code. It is possible to make "id" a variable? This would allow more flexibility. Imagine I am using a code like `for (( FD=3 ; FD < 100 ; FD++ )) ; do exec {FD}> file.$FD ; echo $FD >&${FD}; done`. This would not work, since `exec {FD}> file.${FD}` would be the same descriptor over all values of $FD, right?

Comment: `id` is a variable, you can see it with `echo $id`.

Comment: Nice. To close such descriptor later use `exec {id}<&-`.

Comment: Or is it closed automatically as written here? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181937/how-create-a-temporary-file-in-shell-script

Comment: Arrays can also be used. `declare -a PIPE; exec {PIPE[0]}<>/dev/something`, e.g. `echo Hello World\!>&${PIPE[0]}` and close with `exec {PIPE[0]}>&-`

Comment: @DenioMariz it's possible to use an array to open 100 file descriptors: `for i in {1..100}; do exec {filedescriptors[$i]}<>file.$i; echo $i >&"${filedescriptors[$i]}"; done` see [jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137057/857626) for details

Comment: In my tests on 4.1, you may not use associative array item to seed {id}, so exec {FileDescriptorList[Five]} failed where FileDescriptorList[Five] is 5

Comment: @spioter this is bash 4.3.  But `local -n` works: `x() { local -n a="$1" b="$2" c="$3"; exec {a}<&0 {b}>&1 {c}>&2; }` then `declare -A A; x "A[t1]" "A[t2]" "A[t3]"` or `x=a1 y=a2 z=a3 x "$x" "$y" "$z"` (which gives us something like `{!x}<&0` which isn't in bash

Comment: Sorry, can no more edit previous: `local -n` needs bash 4.3 and above, too, so it only gives us something like `{!var}`

Comment: @FarO: I use this to `export BASH_XTRACEFD=${id}`. When you later unset BASH_XTRACFD the file descriptor will be closed.
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of closing the descriptor, you can put `{}` around the variable.

```
exec {id}>&-
```

The [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) says:

> If `>&-` or `<&-` is preceded by *{varname}*, the value of *varname* defines the file descriptor to close.

Answer (score 0):

I found the discussion in the answer of tobias.pal very interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689974/1184842

```
for (( FD=3 ; FD < 100 ; FD++ )) ; do exec {FD}> file.$FD ; echo $FD >&${FD}; done
```

*This would not work, since `exec {FD}> file.${FD}` would be the same descriptor over all values of $FD, right? (Denio Mariz)*

I solved this by using an array as stated by Drew Chapin:

```
#!/bin/bash
# global variables for temp file handling
declare -a TEMPORARY_FILES_WRITE;
declare -a TEMPORARY_FILES_READ;

function createTempFile() {
    local usecase="$1"
    local id="$2"
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)  # Create a temporal file in the default temporal folder of the system

    # Lets do some magic for the tmpfile to be removed when this script ends, even if it crashes
    exec {TEMPORARY_FILES_WRITE[$id]}>"$tmpfile"
    exec {TEMPORARY_FILES_READ[$id]}<"$tmpfile"
    rm "$tmpfile"  # Delete the file, but file descriptors keep available for this script
}    

for (( FD=3 ; FD < 100 ; FD++ )) ; do 
    TEMP_FILE_COUNTER=$((TEMP_FILE_COUNTER + 1))
    createTempFile "Iteration $FD" $FD ;
    echo $FD >&${TEMPORARY_FILES_WRITE[$FD] ;
done

example=$(cat <&${TEMPORARY_FILES_READ[50]})
echo $example
```

This will output 50.