# Could an existing fd always be duplicated both as input and output?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh, file-descriptor

In bash, once a fd is in use (either as input or output):

```
exec 7>AFile
```

It seems that that fd number could be duplicated, both as input or output:

```
true <&7; echo $?
true >&7; echo $?
```

The tests could be repeated for a variable as:

```
fd=7
rco="$(true >&${fd} 2>/dev/null; echo $?)"
rci="$(true <&${fd} 2>/dev/null; echo $?)"
```

And both exit values joined in one word as:

```
[[ "$rco$rci" = "11" ]] && echo "The fd number $fd is free"
```

The question is:

Under which conditions will the exit value of `"$rco$rci"` be different of `11` for a "free" fd number.

In other words: could it be `10` or `01` sometimes?

Could it be either in other shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never.
Under the hood, the redirections will attempt to [dup](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) an existing or free filedescriptor and then the shell should proceed to run `true` if the preliminary redirections succeeded.

`dup`ing from an unopen descriptor should always fail, which effectively means one attempted redirection in either direction should be enough to test whether a filedescriptor is open or not.

( Conversely,`dup`ing from an open descriptor should almost always succeed. It fails when you've run out of your per-process filedescriptor limit which is usually 1024-4096, and you could theoretically get a permission fail if the shell tried to reset the open flags, but dash, bash, and zsh don't appear to try to do this. I only get IO errors when I actually try to write to a duped readonly filedescriptor, not during the redirection. )

Comment: The last bit is important, because I liked to do `< /dev/null >&0 2>&0`. Now I know that will not fail immediately, only when a write is actually attempted. So `true < /dev/null >&0` "works", but `echo < /dev/null >&0` does not.

Comment: @AndréChalella Yes. For that to work, the file needs to be open for both reading (I'm assuming, you're also going to want reading to work) and writing. You can do that with `<`>, as in `echo <> /dev/null >&0`. If you strace a shell doing that, you should see that `<>` results in open flags `O_RDWR`, whereas for `<` its `O_RDONLY` and for `>` it's `O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.