# Bash parameter expansion, indirect reference, and backgrounding

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, associative-array, variable-declaration

After struggling with this issue for several hours and searching here and failing to come up with a matching solution, it's time to ask:

In bash (4.3) I'm attempting to do a combination of the following:

- Create an array
- For loop through the values of the array with a command that isn't super fast (curl to a web server to get a value), so we background each loop to parallelize everything to speed it up.
- Set the *names* of the values in the array to variables assigned to values redirected to it from a command via "read"
- Background each loop and get their PID into a regular array, *and* associate each PID with the related array value in an associative array so I have key=value pairs of array value name to PID
- Use "wait" to wait for each PID to exit 0 or throw an error telling us which value name(s) in the array failed to exit with 0 by referencing the associative array
- I need to be able export all of the VAR names in the original array and their now-associated values (from the curl command results) because I'm sourcing this script from another bash script that will use the resulting exported VARs/values.

The reason I'm using "read" instead of just "export" with "export var=$(command)" or similar, is because when I background and get the PID to use "wait" with in the next for loop, I actually (incorrectly) get the PID of the "export" command which always exits 0, so I don't detect an error. When I use read with the redirect to set the value of the VAR (from name in the array) and background, it actually gets the PID of the command and I catch any errors in the next loop with the "wait" command.

So, basically, this mostly appears to work, *except* I realized the "read" command doesn't actually appear to be substituting the variable to the array name value properly in a way that the redirected command sends its output to that name in order to set the substituted VAR name to a value. Or, maybe the command is just entirely wrong so I'm not correctly redirecting the result of my command to a VAR name I'm attempting to set.

For what it's worth, when I run the curl | python command by hand (to pull the value and then parse the JSON output) it is definitely succeeding, so I know that's working, I just can't get the redirect to send the resulting output to the VAR name.

Here's a example of what I'm trying to do:
In parent script:

```
# Source the child script that has the functions I need
source functions.sh

# Create the array
VALUES=(
VALUE_A
VALUE_B
VALUE_C
)

# Call the function sourced from the script above, which will use the above defined array
function_getvalues
```

In child (sourced) script:

```
function_getvalues()
{
  curl_pids=( )
  declare -A value_pids
  for value in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
    read ${value} < <(curl -f -s -X GET http://path/to/json/value | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['data']['value'])") & curl_pids+=( $! ) value_pids+=([$!]=${value})
  done
  for pid in "${curl_pids[@]}"; do
    wait "$pid" && echo "Successfully retrieved value ${value_pids[$pid]} from Webserver." || { echo "Something went wrong retrieving value ${value_pids[$pid]}, so we couldn't get the output data needed from Webserver. Exiting." ; exit 1 ; }
  done
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding echo commands to see what the var (var names looped through from array) is set to, and they're blank. I'm not sure if that means they weren't declared at all with the read command (ie substitution isn't working), or if an error in my read redirection as written is failing to send the output of the command to the VAR name to set it.

Comment: Sorry, expected output from the curl command after python json parse is a string. If I run the curl |python by hand I get the expected output, just not with the read redirection.

Comment: Also I'm using python instead of jq because a) I'm just more comfortable with python and b) I'm trying to keep dependencies at a minimum and our team all has python .

Comment: Oh, the & is outside the <( ), just after it, then we get the associative array as the final piece of the command and that has it's own ( ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `read`, when run in the background, [isn't connected](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def#n387) to a standard in.<sup>[[details]](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/shell_read.txt)</sup> Consider this simplified, working example with comment how to cripple it:

```
VALUES=( VALUE_A VALUE_B )
for value in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
    read ${value} < <(echo ${RANDOM}) # add "&" and it stops working
done
echo "VALUE_A=${VALUE_A}"
echo "VALUE_B=${VALUE_B}"
```

You *might* be able to do this with [`coproc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20018504/2908724), or using [`read -u` with automatic file descriptor allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620630/2908724), but really this is a job for temporary files:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

VALUES=( VALUE_A VALUE_B )
for value in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
    (sleep 1; echo ${RANDOM} > "${tmpdir}"/"${value}") &
done
for value in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
    wait_file "${tmpdir}"/"${value}" && {
        read -r ${value} < "${tmpdir}"/"${value}";
    }
done
echo "VALUE_A=${VALUE_A}"
echo "VALUE_B=${VALUE_B}"

rm -r "${tmpdir}"
```

This example uses [`wait_file` helper](https://superuser.com/a/917073/362931), but you might use `inotifywait` if you don't mind some dependencies on OS.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks Bishop. Totally makes sense about read losing its connection to standard in; I had the same concern when I was originally looking at using the 'export' command. I do have one wrinkle on this solution: many of our devs that will run this, are on OS X, and I've read that mktemp behaves differently there. Any insight? I can certainly research this too.

Comment: Yes, there are portability problems with `mktemp`. For resolution, see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84980/50240

Comment: I was able to test that 'mktemp -d' worked the same on both OS X (latest) and Linux, at least on the systems our devs are using, so that's good and portable enough for me.

Comment: Great. If this answer solves the problem, please accept and upvote. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I successfully converted my function(s) to using temp file as described and it works perfectly. Thanks!