# Can I set BASH_XTRACEFD=1 without breaking command substitution?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with output that I'm trying to debug by running bash with `-x`. I'd also like the output to be redirected to stdout instead of stderr (because the logging framework we use treats all stderr content as high-priority errors).

However, command substitutions in my code are failing because the lines logged by `set -x` are getting mixed in with the actual intended output, as shown in the below log.

How can I avoid this bug while directing `set -x` logs to stdout?

Example:

```
root@ee0d2037fdca:/# $(echo "ls")
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@ee0d2037fdca:/# set -x 
root@ee0d2037fdca:/# export BASH_XTRACEFD=1
+ export BASH_XTRACEFD=1
+ BASH_XTRACEFD=1
root@ee0d2037fdca:/# $(echo "ls")
+ ++ echo ls ls
bash: ++: command not found
root@ee0d2037fdca:/#
```

Comment: The string that's prefixed is based on `PS4`; you can change it. That said, I don't at all understand *why* you would do this -- `$(echo "ls")` will be treating the *output from* `ls` as data to be executed every bit as much as it treats the logged/traced command that way as well.

Comment: What's the real goal you're trying to accomplish by using stdout here? There's almost certainly a better way, even if it means just creating a separate copy of the original stdout.

Comment: ...note that per POSIX definition, stdout is only for *output*; "diagnostic" content, which these traces certainly are, is supposed to be routed to stderr.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy We're doing this because we want to see the what our startup process looks like when our containers are started (set -x), and we use command substitution during the startup process, and DataDog sets all output to STDERR with an ERROR flag when I just want it to be INFO

Comment: Personally, I would lean towards fixing that on the datadog end, rather than by changing your script's behavior. They certainly shouldn't be assuming that stderr only contains errors; it's defined as the appropriate place for *all* informational logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of assigning `1` to `BASH_XTRACEFD`, make a new file descriptor with a *copy* of FD 1, and point `BASH_XTRACEFD` to that.

```
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>&1
set -x
$(echo "ls")  # note that this is bad practice; see BashFAQ #50
```

That way your command substitutions change the *real* FD 1, but leave the *copy of the original* FD 1 alone.

---

Note that `{BASH_XTRACEFD}>&1` -- with no leading `$`, and where `BASH_XTRACEFD` is not previously defined -- is deliberate and correct syntax! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620630/14122 describing this syntax, which requires bash 4.1 or later.