# Using a new file descriptor for subsequent bash commands

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I'm trying to follow the [bash advanced scripting guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and use an additional (output) file descriptor. I'm running:

```
3>/tmp/foo
echo hello >&3
```

but instead of this putting "hello" in `/tmp/foo`, I get the error:

```
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

Why is that?

Note: In case it matters, I'm using bash 4.4.

Comment: You shouldn't be arbitrarily picking up file descriptors of choice and start using it. You can let the shell find the next available one, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620630/5291015

Comment: And please don't use tdlp.org. It is archaic, and not does not conform to latest and recommended bash standards. Use the official documentation or Greg's wiki  at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: @Inian: Point taken; see also the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have to say `exec` in order for the the file descriptor creation to apply to subsequent commands. So, this:

```
exec 3>/tmp/foo
echo hello >&3
```

won't give an error message. However, that's bad coding practice, as @Inian suggests. Instead, you should have bash open the smallest available new file descriptor, using the following:

```
exec {my_new_fd}>/tmp/foo
echo hello >&${my_new_fd}
```

that way you can be sure you're not trading on anybody else's file descriptors.