# How to optionally show a progress bar, i.e. stop and show error output in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I successfully use the python tool `tqdm` to display a nice progress bar for e.g. unzipping a large file. However I don't know how to stop that and showing errors from the unzip command if any.

```
#!/bin/bash
function progressBarFiles() {
    local total_files="$1"
    if hash tqdm 2>/dev/null; then
        tqdm --total $total_files --unit files --desc counting | wc -l >/dev/null
    else
        cat
    fi
}
unzip -o huge.zip | progressBarFiles 1697
```

Currently I have the case of unzipping in a network folder fails due to file permission changes failing:

```
counting:   1%|█▉                   | 22/1697 [00:00<00:28, 58.36files/s]
chmod (directory attributes) error: Permission denied
chmod (directory attributes) error: Permission denied
chmod (directory attributes) error: Permission denied
counting:   2%|██▎                  | 26/1697 [00:00<00:35, 46.64files/s]
chmod (directory attributes) error: Permission denied
```

I would like to stop the script after the progress bar and print this error output all together instead of at the moment in unzipping (which breaks the progress bar).

PS: Is the idea with `cat` to have that progress bar completely optional improvable?

Comment: Redirect stderr of the `unzip` to a temp file, cat it to stderr after it's finished.

Comment: Is a temporary file the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this as stated in the comment with redirecting, but with a clean temporary file that will be deleted 100%, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137057/1184842 for more details.